# Updating/removing strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber via Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a custom registration B2C policy where a user is presented with a mobile multi-factor page. If they have not registered before their mobile number is verified and saved against the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber property.

On subsequent logins they must use multi-factor authentication and the verified phone number value is read and populated into the phone number field on-screen with a mask hiding half the numbers. This field is not editable.

In the case where a user loses access to their number, is it possible to update this strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber value or remove it completely from a users account using Graph API? Currently attempting to make a PATCH request using this property results in a 400 response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph API currently does not support this. The only way is for the admin to go to users panel in portal.azure.com and then remove or update the phone number.

Comment: You can now under graph API beta. Log into as yourself here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=<mytenantguid> then you can go to: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userguid>/authentication/emailMethods

I would guess phoneMethods would be the one for that.

Comment: the StrongAuthPhone etc are hard to find (or non obvious to me). I found them under B2C Tenant > Users > Profile > (Section within profile page) Authentication contact info